# Can I dealloc a controller in a method with its own callback block?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

I have a general question about using callback blocks to release a controller all in a given stack frame. This is currently working as desired and the controller is getting a `dealloc` message and no other obvious issues. This is useful (in my opinion) for displaying transient popovers, dialogs and other views without maintaining ivars or other state in the host class. If the xib for the controller is set up to dealloc on close this becomes nice and clean.

This is the *general* pattern:

```
- (void)showTransientView
{
    MyCustomController *controller = nil;

    void(^completeBlock)(ResponseCodeType) = ^(ResponseCodeType response){
        if (response == ResponseOk){
            [self transientViewDidEnd:controller];
        }

        [controller autorelease]; //project is not using ARC
    };

    controller = [[MyCustomController alloc] initWithCallback:completeBlock];
}
```

My question is basically are there hidden problems or other objections here that I am not considering?

Also, how will this change when turning ARC on besides the obvious removal of `[controller autorelease]`?

Comment: If your project isn't using ARC, then the very, very, very first thing you need to do before anything else is to convert it to ARC.

Comment: @gnasher729, it's a very large (old) codebase and we are working on that but would like to use this pattern in several places potentially before that's complete. I want to make sure this strategy is friendly to ARC as well which is why I framed the second question that way.

Comment: You say "this is the _general_ pattern". Can you verify whether `controller` is actually a local variable? That's a crucial point for the question about conversion to ARC.

Comment: Yes, it a local variable.

Comment: I think I've used a similar pattern ages ago. If it works depends on what you're doing within your block - if transientViewDidEnd: behaves foolish, like queuing some methods that depend on the controller but not retain-releasing it, you might be in trouble. As from my experience, transition to ARC was really a HUGE step forward, was not much pain at all due to the converter tool, and saves so much time by avoiding bugs and need to think about memory management in depth; the code is more concise (much shorter), easier to understand. It didn't took a day for a mid-sized app to do the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are doing `autorelease` here as it seems a plain `release` should do the job seems as you are just balancing the `alloc`

---

With ARC there is nothing holding onto that controller so it would be instantly deallocated here.

You could rejig this slightly so that you are passing the completion after instantiation that way the block will actually capture the instance which is what I believe you are trying to achieve.

You will also need to add the `__block` storage specifier to modify `controller` within the block and `nil` out the controller so ARC will send the release

```
__block MyCustomController *controller = MyCustomController.new;

controller.completion = ^{
  controller = nil;
};

// Using weak in this example to ensure the dispatch_after is not the thing holding onto our controller
__weak __typeof(controller) weakController = controller;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  weakController.completion();
});
```

Comment: I presume since the block is copied (and really now lives) in the controller instance and the original on the stack is gone because the stack is gone long before the controller "ends". So the controller is now floating in the heap so the callback would essentially be it committing suicide. I tried this before an IIRC ran into access issues but will try again. Anyway `autorelease` is a soft suicide to work around that.

Comment: With this setup you are essentially creating a deliberate retain cycle with `MyCustomController` holding onto itself. It is then the act of running the completion handler that causes this retain cycle to be broken. If you never run the completion handler and lose a reference to your controller then you will have a nice little memory leak.

Comment: That's actually a very nice distillation of what I am doing. It seems it's a trade-off then: potential memory leaks (depending on the application) or stash a @property for every potential popover and modal in this part of the application. Caveat emptor I guess.

Comment: I've seen the above pattern used without any problems before and it seems perfectly fine as long as you can ensure that the completion handler is called at some point to free up the memory